# Como faço para pegar uma só div com a mesma classe no jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Como posso utilizar a função click no jquery com classes do mesmo nome? Tipo clicar e aparecer o elemento somente na div clicada e não nas demais. Já tentei utilizar `$(this).next('bla').addClass('blablabla')`

e não obtive êxito.

Comment: Não entendi muito bem sua pergunta, você quer que mesma que tenham classes iguais, ele seja inserido apenas na que foi clicada?

Comment: Coloque o código na pergunta. Desta forma não está clara.

Comment: Eu quero clicar numa classe cujo tenha o mesmo nome das outras, só que adicionar uma classe apenas na que foi clicada.

Comment: @darknone já tentou utilizar um id?

Comment: Já e também não funcionou

Comment: Já resolvi, apenas utilizei o siblings :)

Comment: Poderia postar seu código para vermos como ficou!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simples utilize o método [`find`](https://api.jquery.com/find/):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.lista').click(function() {
    $(this).find(".item").toggleClass('green');
  });
});
```

```css
.lista {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 14px;
  padding-bottom: 14px;
}
.item {
}

.green { color: green; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="lista">Clique para mudar a cor do item:<div class="item">pt.stackoverflow.com</div>
</div>
<div class="lista">Clique para mudar a cor do item:<div class="item">pt.stackoverflow.com</div>
</div>
```